# PHP string from array

Tags: php, html, string

I have a function in PHP which prints this

```
Array ( [ladygaga] => 2 [marcus] => 1 [brigstocke] => 1 [georgejeie] => 1 [george] => 1 [dbeckham] => 1 [becks] => 1 ) 1
```

How to I extract the word strings? That is to say, I want to collect the individual strings of each word so I can call each word individually like "lady gaga", "marcus" etc... and then I'll assign these to html parameters

Thank you

Comment: Are you perhaps looking for the [`array_keys` function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php)?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because the solution is trivial, easy to google and obvious by looking at http://php.net/array

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `array_keys` to extract the keys:

```
$strings = array_keys($theArray);

// Gives:

array('ladygaga', 'marcus', 'brigstocke', ...);
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [array_keys()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.array-keys.php)

```
$array = array(0 => 100, "color" => "red");
print_r(array_keys($array));

// returns Array(0, "color");
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [array_keys](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-keys.php) like this

```
$array = Array ( [ladygaga] => 2 [marcus] => 1 [brigstocke] => 1 [georgejeie] => 1 [george] => 1 [dbeckham] => 1 [becks] => 1 ) ;

$keys  = array_keys($array); // This will contain "ladygaga", "marcus" .. as elements
```

Answer (score 0):

If what you're trying to do is call on the words individually as you say, then you might want to look at PHP's foreach loop.   Take a look at the documentation here:  http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php

You can get at just the keys and ignore the values with this:

```
foreach (array_expression as $key => $value)
statement
```